# struct crashes when i run this program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, typedef

I am just practicing with C and I am trying to create a struct with multiple elements in in and loop through and print out all the data in the structs. However when I run this program I am getting a segmentation fault. I a little confused why this is happening since I am able to compile this without any warning or failures and the program runs it just crashes at the end as well.

here is the output when I run the program :

```
lnx-v1:242> ./multiArrayStruct
     Records of EMPLOYEE : 1
 Id is: 1
 First name is: Joe
 Last name is: Johnson
 Employee age is 25
     Records of EMPLOYEE : 2
 Id is: 2
 First name is: Kyle
 Last name is: Korver
 Employee age is 25
     Records of EMPLOYEE : 3
 Id is: 3
 First name is: Adam
 Last name is: Thompson
 Employee age is 25
 Segmentation fault (core dumped) <-------why is this crashing ?
```

here is my code as well :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee 
{
    int empId;
    char empNameFirstName[20];
    char empNameLastName[20];
    int empAge;

};



int main() 
{
        struct employee record[2];

        // First employee record 
        record[0].empId=1;
        strcpy(record[0].empNameFirstName, "Joe");
        strcpy(record[0].empNameLastName, "Johnson");
        record[0].empAge=25;

        // second employee record 
        record[1].empId=2;
        strcpy(record[1].empNameFirstName, "Kyle");
        strcpy(record[1].empNameLastName, "Korver");
        record[1].empAge=25;

        // third employee record 
        record[2].empId=3;
        strcpy(record[2].empNameFirstName, "Adam");
        strcpy(record[2].empNameLastName, "Thompson");
        record[2].empAge=25;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
        {
            printf("     Records of EMPLOYEE : %d \n", i+1);
            printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].empId);
            printf(" First name is: %s \n", record[i].empNameFirstName);
            printf(" Last name is: %s \n", record[i].empNameLastName);
            printf(" Employee age is %d\n", record[i].empAge);

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should make sure you tag what language you are working in. If affects the rendered code as well as makes it easier to find for those who know C.

Comment: array with `[2]` has two entries, `[0]` and `[1]`.  `[2]` is not valid to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an array with 2 elements:

```
    struct employee record[2];
                           ^----
```

which are actually `record[0]` and `record[1]`. But then you try to assign to an undefined THIRD element:

```
    record[2].empId=3;
           ^---
```

which means you're scribbling in unallocated/undefined memory space.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed it by changing to this                               struct employee record[3];